# How does the `prop.table()` function work?

Tags: r

I have trouble finding an (understandable) explanation of what the `prop.table()` function does. I found the following [explanation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/prop.table) and example:

> **prop.table: Express Table Entries as Fraction of Marginal Table**
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> m <- matrix(1:4, 2)
> m
> prop.table(m, 1)
> ```

I do not understand what this explanation means. I've also attempted to discern its functionality from the result of the above example, but I haven't been able to make sense of it.

With reference to the example above, what does the `prop.table()` function do? Furthermore, what is a "marginal table"?

Comment: What do you get for 1÷4, 3÷4, 2÷6, and 4÷6? The 1 in `prop.table` represents row-wise calculations. Try it with 2 instead for comparison.

Comment: If you don't provide a margin, it calculates `m / sum(m)`. With margins, this is done row- or column-wise.

Comment: See also `?margin.table`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The values in each cell divided by the sum of the 4 cells:

```
prop.table(m)
```

The value of each cell divided by the sum of the row cells:

```
prop.table(m, 1)
```

The value of each cell divided by the sum of the column cells:

```
prop.table(m, 2)
```

Answer (score 9):

**I think this can help**

> include all those things like prop.table(m), prop.table(m, 1), prop.table(m, 2)

```
m <- matrix(1:4, 2)
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
> prop.table(m)           #sum=1+2+3+4=10, 1/10=0.1, 2/10=0.2, 3/10=0.3,4/10=0.4
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.1  0.3
[2,]  0.2  0.4
> prop.table(m,1)        
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.2500000 0.7500000  #row1: sum=1+3=4, m(0,0)=1/4=0.25, m(0,1)=3/4=0.75
[2,] 0.3333333 0.6666667  #row2: sum=2+4=6, m(1,0)=2/6=0.33, m(1,1)=4/6=0.66
> prop.table(m,2)        
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.3333333 0.4285714  #col1: sum=1+2=3, m(0,0)=1/3=0.33, m(1,0)=2/3=0.4285
[2,] 0.6666667 0.5714286  #col2: sum=3+4=7, m(0,1)=3/7=0.66, m(1,1)=4/7=0.57
>
```

Answer (score 0):

when m is the 2D matrix: (m,1) refers to a fraction of row marginal table (sum over each row), (m,2) refers to a fraction of column marginal table (sum over each column). In short, just a "% of total sum of row of column", if you dont want to care about the term marginal.

Example:

m with extra row and column margin

```
    [,1] [,2] ***
    [1,]    1    4    5
    [2,]    2    5    7
    [3,]    3    6    9

    *** 6   15  




    > prop.table(m,1)

 `         [,1]      [,2]
    [1,] 0.2000000 0.8000000
    [2,] 0.2857143 0.7142857
    [3,] 0.3333333 0.6666667

    > prop.table(m,2)

          [,1]      [,2]
    [1,] 0.1666667 0.2666667
    [2,] 0.3333333 0.3333333
    [3,] 0.5000000 0.4000000
```

Comment: when prop.table(m, n) where n is NOT specified (absent), then each element is calculated to a percentage of TOTAL SUM of the matrix elements.